# Linux Almalinux - add first available IP adress

Tags: linux, for-loop, ip

```
for i in {1..254}; do
if ! [ grep 10.22.33.$i /etc/hosts ]; then
sudo echo -e "10.22.33.$i ${Name}.${Domain}" >> /etc/hosts
break
fi
done
```

I would like to add the next following ip address that is possible.
Can someone help me with this? for /24 subnet

Comment: Can you please describe the problem you encountered? Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Also: check your script using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) - at a guess you just need to get rid of the square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off your snippet (obviously not a full script, no shebang, and Name & Domain are undefined):

```
for i in {1..254}; do
if ! grep 10.22.33.$i /etc/hosts ; then
    sudo echo -e "10.22.33.$i ${Name}.${Domain}" >> /etc/hosts
    break
fi
done
```

Comment: Ok wow my answer was actually good? the only thing that was wrong where the [ ] , i thought there were needed. In what scenarios those []are needed in a IF statement in linux?

Comment: @JJJ `[` is a synonym for `test`; it requires a binary comparison, something with e.g. `-eq` or `=`. If this solved your problem feel free to accept my answer and/or upvote. The shellcheck I mentioned in the comments above would have told you that. ;)